# Script for deleting files older than N days not working

Tags: windows, shell

I want to delete all files older than one in the folder **c:\Programmes\MySql\Backup**

I am doing this :

```
forfiles -p "c:\Programmes\MySql\Backup" -s -m *.* -d 1 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Windows tells me :

> No file were found with specified criteria

Is there something wrong in this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For earlier dates, it's -1 and not +1: `-d -1`